# Is there a LINQ alternative operator to Where() operator with List.Contains() method inside

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

Using LINQ, is there a faster alternative to a `Where()` method with a `List<T>.Contains()` inside the predicate, that gives *exactly* same results ?

Here is an example :

```
List<int> a = ...
List<int> b = ...

var result = a.Where(x => b.Contains(x)); //very slow
```

One alternative i found is to use `Intersect()` method :

```
var result = a.Intersect(b);
```

In `result` variable, `a` values order is preserved.
However, it does not provide exactly same results if values in `a` contains duplicates, because `Intersect()` operator only return distinct values.

Another way :

```
var result = a.Join(b, x => x, y => y, (x, y) => x);
```

Again results are not the same if `b` contains duplicates.

Is there another possibility ?

What I want to avoid :

- to create my own LINQ extension method
- to create a separate `HashSet` on the first list and to use `Contains()` on inside `Where()`.

Comment: `a.Where(x => b.Contains(a))` should probably be `a.Where(x => b.Contains(x))`

Comment: Unfortunately this is always going to be slow on a `List<T>` because `Contains` is an O(n) operation. You might try `HashSet<T>` but be forewarned that for that to be fast you will need to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for type `T` (assuming `T` is a non-framework type)

Comment: @Mgetz, this is what i suggested in last part using a `Dictionary`. But you are right, using `HashSet` is enough.

Comment: Why are you opposed to putting the items in the second set into a `HashSet`?

Comment: @Servy : I am converting code that already use a lot of Where() + Contains() queries and i want to avoid to add new variables around it.

Comment: @tigrou Then wrap those two lines of code in a new method.  I have no idea why you'd be opposed to doing that either.  Also note it wouldn't be a LINQ extension method, it would just be a new extension method (or you could use a new non-extension static method, if you prefer).  LINQ is, by definition, just what's in the LINQ namespace.  A new extension method you create is a custom extension method, and while it may be of the same style as LINQ, it's not technically LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantically, what you want is a *left inner join*.  The LINQ `Join` operator does an *inner join*, which is close, but not quite the same.  Fortunately you can use a `GroupJoin` to perform a *left join*.

```
var query = from n in a
            join k in b
            on n equals k into matches
            where matches.Any()
            select n;
```

Another option is to put the items in your second sequence into a `HashSet` which can be much more effectively searched than a `List`.  (This is similar to what Join/GroupJoin will do internally.)

```
var set = new HashSet<int>(b);
var query = a.Where(n => set.Contains(n));
```

Another option is to use `Join`, as you did, but simply remove all duplicates from `b` first, because if there are no duplicates then it does what you want:

```
var result = a.Join(b.Distinct(), x => x, y => y, (x, y) => x);
```

Comment: +1 If both collections have duplicates you need a "double group join". Either implement that yourself, or join the results of two normal GroupBy's.

Answer (score 0):

For faster and duplicates I would use the traditional "for".

**Edited**
I wrote a testing code considering:

- Lists with 1000 random ints.
- 200 test per each method.
- 1, 2, 4, and 8 uses of the result to show the need to convert `IEnumerable<int>` result of LINQ to a better data structure like `List<int>` if you use the result many times.

The result are these:

```
1 uses per result
Tigrou-Where        : count=  93,  3.167,0ms
Tigrou-Intersect    : count=  89,    116,0ms
Tigrou-Join         : count=  96,    179,0ms
Servy-GroupJoin     : count=  93,    262,0ms
Servy-HashSet       : count=  93,     71,0ms
Servy-JoinDisctinct : count=  93,    212,0ms
JoseH-TheOldFor     : count=  93,     72,0ms

2 uses per result
Tigrou-Where        : count=  93,  6.007,0ms
Tigrou-Intersect    : count=  89,    182,0ms
Tigrou-Join         : count=  96,    293,0ms
Servy-GroupJoin     : count=  93,    455,0ms
Servy-HashSet       : count=  93,     99,0ms
Servy-JoinDisctinct : count=  93,    407,0ms
JoseH-TheOldFor     : count=  93,     73,0ms

4 uses per result
Tigrou-Where        : count=  93, 11.866,0ms
Tigrou-Intersect    : count=  89,    353,0ms
Tigrou-Join         : count=  96,    565,0ms
Servy-GroupJoin     : count=  93,    899,0ms
Servy-HashSet       : count=  93,    165,0ms
Servy-JoinDisctinct : count=  93,    786,0ms
JoseH-TheOldFor     : count=  93,     73,0ms

8 uses per result
Tigrou-Where        : count=  93, 23.831,0ms
Tigrou-Intersect    : count=  89,    724,0ms
Tigrou-Join         : count=  96,  1.151,0ms
Servy-GroupJoin     : count=  93,  1.807,0ms
Servy-HashSet       : count=  93,    299,0ms
Servy-JoinDisctinct : count=  93,  1.570,0ms
JoseH-TheOldFor     : count=  93,     81,0ms
```

And the code is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
        var cases = 1000;
        List<int> a = new List<int>(cases);
        List<int> b = new List<int>(cases);
        for (int c = 0; c < cases; c++)
        {
            a.Add(random.Next(9999));
            b.Add(random.Next(9999));
        }

        var times = 100;
        var usesCount = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("{0} times", times);
        for (int u = 0; u < 4; u++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} uses per result", usesCount);
            TestMethod(a, b, "Tigrou-Where", Where, times, usesCount);
            TestMethod(a, b, "Tigrou-Intersect", Intersect, times, usesCount);
            TestMethod(a, b, "Tigrou-Join", Join, times, usesCount);
            TestMethod(a, b, "Servy-GroupJoin", GroupJoin, times, usesCount);
            TestMethod(a, b, "Servy-HashSet", HashSet, times, usesCount);
            TestMethod(a, b, "Servy-JoinDisctinct", JoinDistinct, times, usesCount);
            TestMethod(a, b, "JoseH-TheOldFor", TheOldFor, times, usesCount);
            usesCount *= 2;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void TestMethod(List<int> a, List<int> b, string name, Func<List<int>, List<int>, IEnumerable<int>> method, int times, int usesCount)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        int count = 0;
        for (int t = 0; t < times; t++)
        {
            // Process
            var result = method(a, b);
            // Count
            for (int u = 0; u < usesCount; u++)
            {
                count = 0;
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}: count={1,4}, {2,8:N1}ms", 
            name, count, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> Where(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        return a.Where(x => b.Contains(x));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> Intersect(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        return a.Intersect(b); 
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> Join(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        return a.Join(b, x => x, y => y, (x, y) => x);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> GroupJoin(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        return from n in a
               join k in b
               on n equals k into matches
               where matches.Any()
               select n;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> HashSet(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        var set = new HashSet<int>(b);
        return a.Where(n => set.Contains(n));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> JoinDistinct(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        return a.Join(b.Distinct(), x => x, y => y, (x, y) => x);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> TheOldFor(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        var result = new List<int>();
        int countA = a.Count;
        var setB = new HashSet<int>(b);
        for (int loopA = 0; loopA < countA; loopA++)
        {
            var itemA = a[loopA];
            if (setB.Contains(itemA))
                result.Add(itemA);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Changing a line in code to convert the result to `List<int>` before using it thrown these for 8 uses:

```
8 uses per result
Tigrou-Where        : count=  97,  2.974,0ms
Tigrou-Intersect    : count=  91,     91,0ms
Tigrou-Join         : count= 105,    150,0ms
Servy-GroupJoin     : count=  97,    224,0ms
Servy-HashSet       : count=  97,     74,0ms
Servy-JoinDisctinct : count=  97,    223,0ms
JoseH-TheOldFor     : count=  97,     75,0ms
```

So, I think the winner is: the Servy-HashSet method with a little variant:

```
var set = new HashSet<int>(b);
var result = a.Where(n => set.Contains(n)).ToList();
```

Comment: And how, using a `for` loop, do you plan to accomplish this?  If you plan to have two nested loops then your performance is on the order of his first solution, namely bad, because it's an inherently poor algorithm.

Comment: Do you have proof it is faster?

Comment: LINQ is mostly by a constant factor slower than loop-based algorithms. The slowdown can be significant, but it does not change asymptotic complexity.

Comment: a.Where(x => b.Contains(x)) has two neested loops, one for Where an another for Contains, plus calling the anonymous method created from lambda expression and calling of the Contains method for each x.

Comment: @JoséHurtado The question remains, how do you propose to do it *without* two nested loops?

Comment: I never say I didn't use two nested loops... all solution I saw until now has two or more loops implied including passing data previously to another structures like HashSet. 
I understand the requirements are performance and sopport duplicates given two List<T>, not to reduce amount of code or programmer effort.

Comment: @JoséHurtado You can see my answer for three different LINQ based solutions, all of which have underlying algorithms that are faster than two nested `for` loops.  They could all be implemented without LINQ of course, but the `Join` solutions in particular would be rather tedious to write out, and wouldn't likely be dramatically more performant.

Comment: @nmclean, I wrote a test code... And the winner is @Servy! (with a little change).